# Is there any data stored on a raspberry Pi other than on the SD card?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, sd-card, raspberry-pi3

I just want to know, whether I can transfer my pi projects to other pis by simply plugging the sd card into a different pi without damaging any of the projects on them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no data stored on a Raspberry Pi except on the SD card. You may move your card from one Pi to another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is data stored in the **RAM**, but that's no big deal. Just make sure your raspberry pi is off, to avoid corrupting your SD Card (that's happened to me several times). 
But other than that, it **should be just fine** switching out SD Cards to another pi.
Just to be safe, I would recommend using the same Raspberry Pi model (although it probably doesn't matter)